# Set focus on ul li after ngIf performed

Tags: angular

I have `div` with `<ul>` and `<li>` that show after `ngIf` performed as below:

```
<input type="text" />
<button (click)="ShowDropDown=true;">Show</button>
<div *ngIf="ShowDropDown">
  <ul>
    <li (mousedown)="...">...</li>
    <li (mousedown)="...">...</li>
    <li (mousedown)="...">...</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I need to set focus on the very first element of `<li>` after clicking on the `Show` button.

Comment: I've seen this done by custom "autofocus" directive. https://material.angularjs.org/1.0.4/api/directive/mdAutofocus (I know the link is for angular 1, but the basic idea should be the same)

Comment: use `ngStyle` to add `focus` style in the html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have updated my solution to use getter/setter.
I have add tabindex as mentioned by @Faisal.
In template:

```
<button (click)="showDropDown=true;">Show</button>
<div #container>
<div *ngIf="showDropDown">
  <ul>
    <li tabindex="0" (mousedown)="select">1</li>
    <li (mousedown)="select">2</li>
    <li (mousedown)="select">3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
</div>
```

And in component:

```
  private _showDropDown = false;

  get showDropDown () {
    return this._showDropDown;
  }

  set showDropDown (val) {
    this._showDropDown = val;
    this.focusOnFirstLi();
  }

  @ViewChild('container') myDiv;

  focusOnFirstLi () {
     var that = this;
     setTimeout(function () {
       that.myDiv.nativeElement.getElementsByTagName("li")[0].focus();
     }, 10);
  }
```

[https://plnkr.co/edit/Dc3Eh35QX9kiHg3YsSBR?p=info](http://Demo%20on%20Plunker.)

Comment: Hi, I have similar issue, want to display focus on the first 'li' part. The above solution is not working for me. I have ng-if and it is on ng-template. Can you help me with the same? @BadisMerabet

Answer (score 10):

```
<input type="text" #myInput />
<button (click)="ShowDropDown=true;">Show</button>
<div *ngIf="ShowDropDown">
  {{ myInput.focus() }}
  <ul>
    <li (mousedown)="...">...</li>
    <li (mousedown)="...">...</li>
    <li (mousedown)="...">...</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

put attention on **{{ myInput.focus() }}** inside ngIf and **#myInput** inside the input

Comment: This is the only solution that works with ngIf on the input/form-field (Angular 9) ! Thanks !

Answer (score 5):

For setting focus on element like `div`, `li` etc., you need to set a `tabindex` attribute for them. Here is how you can set the focus on button click:

**Change your component html to this:**

```
<button (click)="showDropDown()">Show</button>
<div *ngIf="toggleDropDown">
  <ul>
    <li #firstLi tabindex="0">...</li>
    <li >...</li>
    <li >...</li>  
  </ul>
</div>
```

**... and in your component class to:**

```
toggleDropDown: boolean = false;
  @ViewChild('firstLi') firstLi:ElementRef;
  public showDropDown(){
      this.toggleDropDown=true
      setTimeout(()=>{
        this.firstLi.nativeElement.focus();
      },10);
  }
```

---

Here is a working plunker: [**DEMO**](https://plnkr.co/edit/QfbeM0cLF0JezCkdmOZO)